# Is it possible to play video file using file stream in asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, video

I have a file stream of the .flv file and i want to play the video using with file stream in asp.net page.

I am able to play the video with this local file path in asp.net page (using object tag)

is it possible to play video using filestream in asp.net? if so please explain how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to do [like this video streaming](http://stage.orchestra.it/), you can use it based on this [blog post](http://blogs.ugidotnet.org/kfra/archive/2006/10/04/50003.aspx).

> Using this HTTP handler you can easily FLV streaming downloads just
>   like video.google.com does.